How to replace various strings in dataset column in R
I am working with a dataset that has about 9000 observations. One of the columns includes race and most of the observations have race listed as 'White', 'Black', 'Hispanic', etc.. However, there are some where the observation has multiple races. I included a picture below of all the races.

I would like to replace these with 'Mixed' instead of having 'Black,Hispanic', 'White,Black', and so on.  How can I do this?

Using sub and data from @Andre Wildberg...
df$race <- sub(".*,.*", "Mixed", df$race)
df
      race
1    Black
2    White
3    Mixed
4 Hispanic
5    Mixed


I used gsub instead of sub and it did the trick!

@prinasikowitz in your original data there is probably sometimes more than one comma, so you need gsub

If , is the delimiter, using replace with grepl
transform(df, race_new = replace(race, grepl(",", race), "Mixed"))
                  race race_new
1                Black    Black
2                White    White
3       Black,Hispanic    Mixed
4             Hispanic Hispanic
5 White,Black,Hispanic    Mixed

Keep in mind that , should only occur as delimiter, not in the race strings itself.
Data
df <- structure(list(race = c("Black", "White", "Black,Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
"White,Black,Hispanic")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))


mutate() and case_when() can help. Please see this simple demo:
library(dplyr)

tibble(
  nz_race_group = c(
    # Default groups:
    
    "European",
    "Māori",
    "Pacific Peoples",
    "Asian",
    "Middle Eastern/Latin American/African",
    "Other Ethnicity",
    
    # Mixed groups:
    "A + B",
    "A + B + C",
    "B + D")) |> 
  
  mutate(
    
    nz_race_group = case_when(
      
      nz_race_group %in% c("European",
                           "Māori",
                           "Pacific Peoples",
                           "Asian",
                           "Middle Eastern/Latin American/African",
                           "Other Ethnicity") ~ nz_race_group,
      
      TRUE ~ "Mixed")
  )

And the result becomes:
# A tibble: 9 × 1
  nz_race_group                        
  <chr>                                
1 European                             
2 Māori                                
3 Pacific Peoples                      
4 Asian                                
5 Middle Eastern/Latin American/African
6 Other Ethnicity                      
7 Mixed                                
8 Mixed                                
9 Mixed                                

In this example, the case_when() keep the  default groups and only changes the mixed groups to Mixed. Hope it is helpful.

Please add to your answer that the dplyr package has to be loaded first. (Or tidyverse.)
